# Nightly Update DB with Windows Service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, windows-services

I am very new to the windows services. and am trying to create an application that will update the db nightly.

i already have the code that works (for the update itself)

but i can't figure out how to code it within the service.

```
  Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.

    Dim timerDelegate As New TimerCallback(UpdateDB)
    serviceTimer = New Timer(timerDelegate, Nothing, 0, 20000)

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
End Sub
```

as far as i understand, the above code will rune very 20 seconds, right?  how can i code it so it only runs once a day... at let's say midnight.

thank you!

or should i be using a web service? can i schedule that?

Comment: I just need to jump in and tell you that you're life will be ten times easier if you abandon the Windows Service route and just make a console application that you schedule using the Window's Task Scheduling service. I know you say that your code is working but in a year when something funky happens and you need to debug it you'll find debugging a console app is way easier. Additionally you can manually run a console app whenever you want whereas your service has the timer hard-coded in it (or you're reading it from a config file).

Comment: thank you chris. since im not that far our yet. i'll try it now. Windows Console Application, right?

Comment: good luck! Writing a Windows service it pretty easy and there's even some great open source frameworks that make it even easier but I generally recommend services only for programs that need to constantly be running or that need to respond to machine condition changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to use a windows service?

A simpler approach would be to create a console application and use the windows scheduler to launch it.

Windows services can be a pain to install and debug so I would only use them when absolutely necessary.

Comment: it worked perfectly, and muuuch easier then i expected! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to have your timer execute on a `1000ms` interval (depending on how exact/close you need to be to actual midnight).  Obviously, the lower your interval, the closer you'll be to getting exactly to midnight.

You could increase this, to say, every 5 minutes if you wanted less activity to occur within the timer, and if your threshold for execution could be +5 minutes after midnight.

Each time your timer fires, you'd then check the current time against the time you are attempting to fire an event off at, in this case midnight.

If the current time is midnight, or within the threshold of your defined of midnight, then execute your code.