# Terminate thread execution for 24 hours

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, service, windows-services

I have my service working mostly as it should, but it should only do it's work once every day.

To arrange this, my boss recommended I sleep the worker thread until 7am tomorrow:

This `Thread.Sleep` call is copied directly from a similar service he wrote that apparently works, but this always throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException - the value returned is a negative.

```
    Private Sub startExport()
#If Not Debug Then
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 1)
#End If
        While runReportExport
            Try
                runExport()
            Catch ex As Exception
                el.WriteEntry("Error exporting data: {1}")
            Finally
                'sleep thread until tomorrow 7am
                Thread.Sleep(DateTime.Now.Subtract(Date.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(7)))
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub
```

I'm fairly confused about how this all works so if anyone can explain the whole timespan thing for me, I'd greatly appreciate it.

On the other hand, my friend recommends I manage the thread execution in a different way.

Here's what He recommended I do:

```
Private lastExecute As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Private Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    startService()
End Sub

Private Sub startService()
    Dim nextExecute = lastExecute.AddDays(1)
    If nextExecute >= DateTime.Now Then
        lastExecute = DateTime.Now

        tWorker = New Thread(AddressOf startExport)
        tWorker.IsBackground = True
        tWorker.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```

He said this would execute the worker thread once on startup and not again for another day. While this code does work without error, it doesn't stop the service loop from executing the worker thread over and over again (currently it executes a 2nd time as soon as it finished it's first run)

Personally I'm open to either approach, I can't seem to get either working.

Basically, all I need at the end of the day is a service that exports data once daily.

My boss' Thread.Sleep option seems the simpler, but my friend's suggestion seems like better practice.

Can anyone help me to get this sorted (at this point I don't care which one I use, just so long as it works)?

Comment: Is there some requirement to run it as a service rather than a scheduled task? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749026/nightly-update-db-with-windows-service

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I was just told to write it as a service and given the current state of my employment, it's better for me to not question orders

Comment: Maybe you could say you did a little research (shows enthusiasm) and found a better, more robust, way to run the program on a schedule.

Comment: The correct way of doing this is to employ a scheduled task

Comment: So in telling me to use a scheduled task for this, am I supposed to infer that there is no way to do this in a windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DateTime.Now.Subtract(Date.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(7)))
```

You subtract a future time from the current time.  That always produces a negative value.  Kaboom.

You'll need to invert that, subtracting the current time from the future time.  Spelled out for clarity and avoiding the race on DateTime.Now :

```
Dim today = DateTime.Now
Dim tomorrow = today.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(7)
Dim wait = tomorrow - today
Thread.Sleep(wait)
```

You will need to do something useful when the service is stopped.  Best done with a ManualResetEvent, you'll get the sleep from its WaitOne(wait) method.  Btw, extremely wasteful to have a thread sleep for that long and not doing anything useful.  Use a Timer instead.

Comment: +1 for spotting the bug and not just recommending a different approach.  For such a long interval, I would probably suggest using a timer or scheduled task too, but you fixed the bug as well :)

Comment: Annoyingly, I spotted the bug about an hour after posting this after going through what all the date things are doing with a fine toothed comb so to speak... But I'm too lazy to write my own answer which would essentially be this answer here, so accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, and one I use, to run a specific task once a day is to set the task up in a timer.  In my case I want the task to run at 12:05am each morning.   Accordingly, when my program starts I set the initial interval of the timer such that the first tick will happen at 12:05 am the next day.  After that, once a day, at the end of the code the executed as part of the tick I once again reset the timer interval such that the next tick will happen at 12:05am the next day.

```
...

Timer1.Interval = MillisecondsToMidnight() + 300000 ' next tick 12:05:00 tomorrow

...

Private Function MillisecondsToMidnight() As Integer

    Dim ReturnValue As Integer
    Dim ts As TimeSpan

    Dim Tomorrow As DateTime = Today.AddDays(1)
    ts = Tomorrow.Subtract(Now)

    ReturnValue = ts.TotalMilliseconds()

    ts = Nothing
    Return ReturnValue

End Function
```